# Can't login using laravel/socialite package. Instead, getting invalidToken error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I used laravel/socialite package for social signin but, can't signin through GitHub.

I followed the below url 
https://www.sitepoint.com/easily-add-social-logins-to-your-app-with-socialite/

I expect to login through GitHub but, the actual output is invalidToken on callback url instead and is redirected to login page.

Comment: did you added the Client Id and Client Secret in your .env file?

Comment: yes. Configuration part and code-wise, I have implemented as instructed in the link which I followed. The code does not have execution errors but, GitHub login does not work properly; other social logins not tried yet.

Comment: maybe is a session cookie issue. try to access in a incognito window

Comment: No.. just tried. It doesn't work with incognito either.